# scan to a struct fields that some of them are pointers

Tags: postgresql, go, pointers

I'm writing a GO application and I'm trying to find an easy method to scan a row from the database to struct fields.

I use pgx to connect to a postgresql database

gqlgen generated this class:

```
type Profile struct {
    Name      string          `json:"name"`
    JoinedAt  time.Time       `json:"joined_at"`
    Bio       *string         `json:"bio"`
}
```

and then I'm got the function to get the user profile from db:

```
func GetUserProfile(ctx context.Context, profileDir string) (*model.Profile, error) {
    sqlQuery := `select name,joined_at::timestamptz,bio from foo where profile_dir=$1`
    var profile model.Profile
    if err := Connection.QueryRow(ctx, sqlQuery, profileDir).
        Scan(&profile.Name, &profile.JoinedAt, &profile.Bio); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    } else {
        return &profile, nil
    }
}
```

now since `Bio` is a pointer, I need to create a variable who's not a pointer, scan to it and assign it's address after that to the struct:

```
var profile model.Profile
var mybio string
...
Connection.QueryRow(...).Scan(...,&mybio)
profile.Bio=&mybio
```

is there an easier way to scan a row to a struct that might have pointers ?

Comment: Is there any reason why bio is a pointer in the first place?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco - gqlgen generates classes like that (graphql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Bio` is already a pointer, you don't need to take an extra pointer in the Scan call:

```golang
profile := Profile{
    Bio: new(string),
}

if err := Connection.QueryRow(ctx, sqlQuery, profileDir).
    Scan(&profile.Name, &profile.JoinedAt, profile.Bio); err != nil {
    return nil, err
} else {
    return &profile, nil
}
```

Comment: I can't scan to the actual pointers because they are nil, they are not allocated

Comment: Right, I added the correct instantiation of `Profile` to the answer above. Note: `new` creates a pointer of given type.